# MULTISITE SUB-DOMAIN JUST SHOWS INDEX OF -> CGI-BIN INSTEAD OF SHOWING SITE

Tags: multisite, htaccess, wp-config

I created a multisite with sub-domain (site1.example.com). The Sub domain page just shows Index of -> cgi-bin instead of showing the actual website.

I do not know exactly how sub domains work in WordPress multisite network but i have already few websites (app.example.com) as a sub domain that are separate WordPress instances and not part of this network.

But sub domains that are part of this network displaying error message (Index of cgi bin).I have followed instructions from codex and then create a sub domain in my cpanel and then i create a website in my network but that is not working.

Any help will be much appreciated because this is my first experience with multisite. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I was pointing to wrong directory. Actually WordPress requires sub domain (site1.example.com) to point to the root directory of main website (example.com).
Previously in cpanel my sub domain path was public_html/site1 and now i change this to public_html/ and everything started to work properly.